# JQuery .css bottom property not applying css to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

```
   var startingWindowSize = $(window).width();
   var startPercent = 70;
    if( startingWindowSize >= 1920 )
    {
        startPercent = 70; 
        $('.rsImg').css({bottom: startPercent+"%"});    
    }
    else if( startingWindowSize >= 1440 )
    {
        startPercent = 40;  
        $('.rsImg').css({bottom: startPercent+"%"});   
    }
    else if( startingWindowSize >= 1280 )
    {
        startPercent = 18; 
        $('.rsImg').css({bottom: startPercent+"%"});        
    }
    else
    {
        startPercent = 10; 
        $('.rsImg').css({bottom: startPercent+"%"});        
    }
```

Why would this code not be working? It refuses to add the style to the tag. There is already some css being added before this code before this snippet by a javascript slider plugin. Could this be the cause? The slider can be found [here](http://natty.appstudios.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$('.rsImg')` actually refers to the correct item?
Try `alert($('.rsImg').size())` to double-check that it actually found what you think it did.

Also, are you sure this code is running after the page has finished loading? Is it in an `onready` callback function?

This isn't entirely related, but your code can be simplified by only doing the `.css()` call once:

```
var startingWindowSize = $(window).width();
var startPercent = 10;

if (startingWindowSize >= 1920) startPercent = 70; 
else if (startingWindowSize >= 1440) startPercent = 40;  
else if (startingWindowSize >= 1280) startPercent = 18; 

$('.rsImg').css({bottom: startPercent+"%"});
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying! But sadly, it still didn't work. And I am 200% positive .rsImg is the correct item. I have implemented your code. If you go to site and inspect the slider image, you can see that css is being applied to the element, just not the bottom property.

Comment: Actually, the CSS is getting applied... if I browse the DOM of the page, I see `style="bottom: 40%;"` on every `.rsImg` `<img>` tag. So it's actually a styling issue - the `bottom: 40%` CSS isn't having the effect you expect.

Comment: That's weird because when I add a bottom property in the style sheet, it works just I expect it too. What browser are you are using? I'm using Chrome and I do not see it being added when I browse the DOM...

Comment: It's like the jQuery can't do anything to an image object with the rsImg class. I've tried adding classes, different css styles, etc and nothing happens. So frustrated right now.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well. It showed up the first time I tried it, but not when I tried again later.

Comment: Looking at the code that's currently online, it looks like you copied the if/else block above, but forgot the last line that actually applies the CSS. Can you double-check that?

Comment: I had been messing with it.
 var startingWindowSize = $(window).width();
    var startPercent = 10;
     if (startingWindowSize >= 1920) startPercent = -70; 
  else if (startingWindowSize >= 1440) startPercent = -40;  
  else if (startingWindowSize >= 1280) startPercent = -18; 

  $('.rsImg').css({bottom: startPercent+"%"});

This is what I have uploaded and this should work, but does not...

Comment: When I add negative percentages to the bottom property in the stylesheet, it moves the image up, which is what I want to happen. I know, it's weird.

Comment: It looks like the `bottom: -40%` style is getting moved from the `<img>` tag to second-level parent `<div>`, probably by the slider code.

Comment: Oh, I mean't for that to happen. I changed it to .rsSlide and that code works fine, so I don't know why using .rsImg doesn't work.

Comment: Just decided to use css media screen jumps instead of jQuery. Not worth the hassle or the frustration. I appreciate all the help though!

Comment: I agree, that's probably simpler. I suspect it's the slider code that's directly setting the `style` attribute or something. Using CSS directly will avoid that entirely. Another option might be to use the javascript like you are now, but just add a size-specific class instead of applying the CSS directly. (.bottom40 or .bottom70, for example)